# Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p [x]$, where $p$ is prime, be defined by $f(x) = x^p - x$. Show that its Polynomial evaluation is identically zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

I understand that Fermat's Little Theorem is crucial here, but I am not sure how to tie the whole thing together...

Observe: If $f(a) \equiv 0$ then $a^p - a \equiv 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ $\implies a^p \equiv a\mod p$

So, proof: Since $p$ is prime, then $a^p \equiv a\mod p$ $\implies a^p - a \equiv 0 \mod p$ $\implies f(a) \equiv 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Is this enough or am I incorrectly assuming something?

Comment: It looks fine to me. A little repetitive, but correct.

Comment: I guess I just wasn't sure if it was valid to subtract $a$ from the congruence relation in Fermat's little theorem

Comment: The equality $\;a^p=a\pmod p\;$ means **exactly** that $\;a^p=a\;$ in the field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ , and you certainly can substract same thing from both sides of an equality.

Comment: I thought congruence doesn't quite mean equality? For instance, $a^p \equiv a \mod p$ $\implies pk = (a^p - a)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The congruence is in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , the equality in $\;\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z_p\;$ . These two are two very different algebraic structures.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused... What is $\mathbb{F}_p$? I thought it was different naming convention for $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: $\;\Bbb F_{p^r}\;$ is the (unique up to isomorphism) field with $\;p^r\;$ elements, $\;p\;$ a prime. For $\;k=1\;$, the field is exactly the same object as $\;\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ . Caution: this is **not so** for $\;r>1\;$ .

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for the help!!!