# Polynomial $x^p - x$ has no multiple roots over any extension of $Z_p$ if $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

How to prove that $f(x) = x^p - x$ has no polynomial roots over any extension of $Z_p$ given $p$ is prime?

I know that

$f(x)$ has no multiple roots $\iff \gcd(f, f') = 1$

$f'(x) = px^{p-1} - 1 \equiv -1  \pmod p $

Hence $\gcd(f, f') = 1$ and $f$ has no multiple roots over $Z_p[x]$.

Comment: I think you mean multiple roots over any extension of $\mathbb Z_p$.  $\mathbb Z_p$ (the integers mod prime $p$) is a field, $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ is not. There are already $p$ distinct roots over $\mathbb Z_p$, namely $0,1,2, \ldots, p-1$.  A polynomial of degree $p$ can't have more than $p$ roots (counting multiiplicity), so no field extension. can introduce any more.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: @LUDec Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%20%3D%20x%5Ep%20-%20x%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24Z_p%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), a fairly closely related question is [Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p [x]$, where $p$ is prime, be defined by $f(x) = x^p - x$. Show that its Polynomial evaluation is identically zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1736671/602049).

Answer (score 1):

You have already proven it by showing that $f'(x)$ has no root. If $f(x)=(x-a)^2h(x)$, then $$f'(x)=2(x-a)h(x)+(x-a)^2h'(x)$$ so that $f(a)=f'(a)=0$.